# How do I sort a dataframe's columns based on the values in multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,3,3], 'y':['a','a','c','b','b','b']})
ct = pd.crosstab(df.x, df.y)
ct
y  a  b  c
x         
1  2  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  2  0
```

How do I sort the columns of ct based on the values in row1, row2, and row3 (in that order of priority)?

I've tried the following, neither of which work

```
ct.sort_values([1, 2, 3], axis=1)
ct.sort_values(['1','2','3'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Your example is a bit odd because row 1 already completely specifies the order of the result, so the lower-priority sorts on other rows will have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot currently be done with a direct call to `sort_values`.  There is [an open bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10806) about it.

You can still do it less nicely by transposing, sorting by columns, then transposing again:

```
>>> ct.T.sort_values([1, 2, 3]).T
y  b  c  a
x         
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  0
3  2  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should sort them in order of a>b>c:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,3,3], 'y':['a','a','c','b','b','b']})
ct = pd.crosstab(df.x, df.y)

y  a  b  c
x         
1  2  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  2  0

sorted_df = pd.DataFrame(ct.sort_values(by = ['a','b','c'], ascending = [False,False,False]))

y  a  b  c
x         
1  2  0  1
3  0  2  0
2  0  1  0
```