# How to add a new row to an existing DataFrame which is the sum of two rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame looks as follow:

```
      Name1  Name2
Val1    1.2    2.2
Val2    2.3    4.2
```

What I want is as follow:

```
      Name1  Name2
Val1    1.2    2.2
Val2    2.3    4.2 
Val3   0.52   0.52
```

The values in `Val3` is `Val1/Vals2`.

How to do that?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.loc` to grab each row individually](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) and divide them.  Use [`.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to append the result to the end of the original data frame.

```
# Mocking up your example data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name1':(1.2, 2.3), 'Name2':(2.2, 4.2)}, index=('Val1', 'Val2'))

# The solution
new_row = df.loc['Val1'] / df.loc['Val2']
new_row.name = 'Val3'
df.append([new_row])
```

Comment: Your answer is great!

Comment: Furhter question: if I want to sort (descindingly) the columns according the values of the last row, how to do that?

Comment: @thomas Sorting columns by values in a row is not so easy, but still possible. Read the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/34689164/850883