# Pandas sort row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3
1   1092  203   802
```

Is it possible to sort this dataframe and get a result like this：

```
    Col1  Col3  Col2
1   1092  802   203
```

I tried `sort_values` but it doesn't work. My work around is `df.T.sort_values(...)`

Comment: Do you have just one row? Or you want to sort it according to the first row?

Comment: Your solution of transposing, sorting, and transposing again is the current solution. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689164/how-do-i-sort-a-dataframes-columns-based-on-the-values-in-multiple-rows) and [bug report](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10806).

Comment: @NickilMaveli I only have one row

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting from `0.19.0`, you could sort the columns based on row values.

```
df.sort_values(by=1, ascending=False, axis=1)
```

[image]

---

***Bar chart:***

Using ggplot:

```
melt_df = pd.melt(df, var_name='Cols')
ggplot(aes(x="Cols", weight="value"), melt_df) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Using built-in:

```
melt_df.plot.bar(x=['Cols'], y=['value'], legend=False, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Er, this doesn't work if your table has more than one row, right?