# Group by and sum over rows with same contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame of 3 columns with numerical values, first two columns  are a set with two elements. I want to treat the rows of these 2 columns as a set (that contains the same elements) and group by + sum:

```py
df.groupby([A,B]).sum() --- won't work here
```

example:

```
 A        B   counter
750     1334    10
1080    1920    15
1080    1920    10
1920    1080    10
1125    2436    20
```

result :

```
 A        B   counter
750     1334    10
1080    1920    35
1125    2436    20
```

Comment: expected result?

Comment: `df.groupby([A,B])['counter'].sum()`?

Comment: @ALollz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662717/groupby-two-columns-ignoring-order-of-pairs/53662762?r=SearchResults&s=1|39.7525#53662762

Answer (score 3):

Idea is sorting both columns by [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and reassign back:

```
df[['A','B']] = np.sort(df[['A','B']], axis=1)

df = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False)['counter'].sum()
print (df)
      A     B  counter
0   750  1334       10
1  1080  1920       35
2  1125  2436       20
```

Or assign to array passed to `groupby`:

```
arr = np.sort(df[['A','B']], axis=1)
df = df.groupby([arr[:, 0],arr[:, 1]])['counter'].sum().rename_axis(('A','B')).reset_index()
print (df)
      A     B  counter
0   750  1334       10
1  1080  1920       35
2  1125  2436       20
```

Comment: Still weird to me that we cannot use `df.sort_values(['A', 'B'], axis=1)` And we need to reach out to `numpy` for this

Comment: @Erfan - it is used if need sorting by one row only

Comment: @Erfan - https://stackoverflow.com/q/40438656

Comment: I see, but there should be `pandas` way to sort over `axis=1`

Comment: @Efran, likely because with panel data you often have a mixture of numeric and categorical data, so it's often rare that you'd be able to sort across columns anyway. That and for the most of the time, two unordered columns with the same information are often organized better as a single longer table.