# Sorting crosstab data in pandas for more clustered heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap

I'm trying to make more clustered heatmap of some association data. The data consists of association of two lists of factors (CatA and CatB factors). A sample (30) from data (550) is below.

```
CatA_Factors    CatB_Factors
CatA_Factor_150 CatB_Factor_31
CatA_Factor_137 CatB_Factor_30
CatA_Factor_111 CatB_Factor_22
CatA_Factor_80  CatB_Factor_1
CatA_Factor_93  CatB_Factor_15
CatA_Factor_44  CatB_Factor_3
CatA_Factor_80  CatB_Factor_30
CatA_Factor_58  CatB_Factor_1
CatA_Factor_151 CatB_Factor_1
CatA_Factor_138 CatB_Factor_30
CatA_Factor_138 CatB_Factor_31
CatA_Factor_93  CatB_Factor_22
CatA_Factor_5   CatB_Factor_27
CatA_Factor_99  CatB_Factor_10
CatA_Factor_142 CatB_Factor_30
CatA_Factor_16  CatB_Factor_30
CatA_Factor_29  CatB_Factor_27
CatA_Factor_103 CatB_Factor_23
CatA_Factor_65  CatB_Factor_31
CatA_Factor_48  CatB_Factor_8
CatA_Factor_69  CatB_Factor_12
CatA_Factor_69  CatB_Factor_13
CatA_Factor_150 CatB_Factor_31
CatA_Factor_45  CatB_Factor_12
CatA_Factor_69  CatB_Factor_12
CatA_Factor_33  CatB_Factor_12
CatA_Factor_116 CatB_Factor_30
CatA_Factor_29  CatB_Factor_27
CatA_Factor_116 CatB_Factor_24
CatA_Factor_112 CatB_Factor_27
```

I'm using pandas crosstab. `pandas.crosstab(df['CatA_Factors'],df['CatB_Factors'])`
This gives how often an association occurs in the data. When I plot a heatmap using code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

dfAB = pd.read_excel('CatABC.xlsx', sheet_name=0, engine='openpyxl')

dfABx = pd.crosstab(dfAB['CatA_Factors'], dfAB['CatB_Factors'])
plt.subplots(figsize=(15,30))
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10, labelbottom = False, bottom=False, top = True, labeltop=True)
sns.heatmap(dfABx, cmap="Reds", linewidth=1, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
```

I get this plot: [image]

However, I'd like it to be more clustered i.e. more frequently occurring associations to be presented towards top left corner. I managed to get the crosstab frequency data into excel and then transposed it, calculated average of each row and stored it in a column, then sorted in descending order according to that. Then transpose again, calculated average of each row and stored it in a column, then sorted in descending order according to that. There are two problems

1. The data seems to be good but I'm unable to bring it back to pandas data frame to generate the heat map.
2. My process is very manual. I'd want to be able to do this in python/pandas but I need some help. For instance to transpose the crosstab then add an average column, then sort according to that column, then transpose back, then add another average column, sort according to that column. Please let me know how to make it work or a better alternative. Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Could you please copy the data and paste it into a code block in the question?

Comment: @medium-dimensional sorry about this. The data is like 550 rows. Is there any way to include that in the post or would you rather I copy say about 30 rows from excel?

Comment: No worries. I think you could copy first 30 rows and paste it so that others can copy the data and implement their solution to show the proof of concept. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`clustermap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) instead of [`heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
sns.clustermap(dfABx, cmap="Reds", linewidth=1, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Having some difficulty with pip install scipy as it's one of the requirements. @mozway May I please request the solution with heatmap? The output is cleaner there and I do run into similar data cleaning situations that I've highlighted so it will save time in future too. Something like this may be? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34689212

Comment: You should probably try to solve your issue with the installation of `scipy`. Clustering is more complex than a simple sorting of the values.

Comment: I've been trying to resolve that but to no success so far. I'm still keen on the sorting related query because I've run into similar problems and have had to do manually. Should I ask an independent SO question about that separately? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Rys as you want, but in any case, what about providing a small example dataset, explaining the exact logic you have in mind (as if you were doing it on pen and paper) and providing the matching expected output?

Comment: Allow me to ask a side question to be able to share the dataset and my current process. Can I use pastebin or something else to just share my dataframe? so you could have access to it? The code is already in the existing post. I've tried doing transpose and mean on it and getting closer somehow.